# Помогите понять, что означает такая запись массива в блок-схеме

Tags: c++

s[j,1] , либо s[j, 2]

где J переменная циклу.
Если не сложно буду благодарен.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Массив двухмерный? Может имели в виду `s[j][1]`?

Comment: Нет не двухмерний.

Answer (score 0):

означает, что в двухмерном массиве `s` надо на 1 увеличить значение в ячейке `[j, 2]` (`j`_ая строка, `2`-ой столбец)